# SQLite - Check table format on CREATE and drop if needed

Tags: python, sqlite

Say I need a table that has to have two columns (A TEXT, B TEXT).
Every time before I run a program, I want to check if the table exists, and create it if it doesn't. Now say that the table with that name exists already, but has only one column (A TEXT), or maybe (A INT, B INT)

So in general, different columns.
How do I check that on CREATE query? And if there's a conflict back it up somewhere and drop, then create a new correct table. If there's no conflict - don't do anything.

I am working in Python, using sqlite3 by the way. Database is stored locally for now and program is distributed to multiple people, that's why I need to check the database.

Currently I have

```
con = sqlite3.connect(path)
with con:
  cur = con.cursor()
  cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (A TEXT, B TEXT);')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pragma `table_info` in order to get information about the table, and use the result to check your columns:

```
def validate(connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('PRAGMA table_info(table)')
    columns = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return (len(columns) == 2
            and columns[0][1:3] == ('A', 'TEXT')
            and columns[1][1:3] == ('B', 'TEXT'))
```

So if validate returns `False` you can rename the table and create the new one.

Comment: Awesome, is there any way to automate that a little bit more though? I'm not a biggest fan of hardcoding the check for columns. My column info is pulled from config file and it has 5 columns

Comment: For sure you can use a for loop and then check the columns against the data in the config

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what I'll have to do